# Determing the type of number stored as a string

Tags: python

How do I tell whether a number, stored as a string, is an int or a float?

For example:

```
def isint(x):
    if f(x):
        print 'this is an int'
    else:
        print 'this is a float'

>>> x = '3'
>>> isint(x)
>>> this is an int
>>> x = '3.14159'
>>> isint(x)
>>> this is a float
```

**What is the required `f(x)` function?**

One solution is to convert x to a float, find `r = x % 1`, and then determin whether `r == 0`. But is there anything built into Python that does this for me more neatly?

Comment: What should be the result for `isint('3.0')`?

Comment: Yes, good point! I would want it to tell me that '3.0' is a float in this case. I think that the answer below addresses that too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval):

```
>>> from ast import literal_eval
>>> type(literal_eval('1.01'))
<type 'float'>
>>> type(literal_eval('1'))
<type 'int'>
>>> type(literal_eval('1+0j'))
<type 'complex'>
```

If you want to do some sanity check as well, in case user might also pass a non-numeric string:

```
import numbers
from ast import literal_eval

def number_type(x):
    try:
        n = literal_eval(x)
        if isinstance(n, numbers.Number):
            print type(n).__name__
        else:
            print 'not a number' 
    except (ValueError, SyntaxError):
        print 'not a number'
```

Comment: So how do I actually implement this in `f(x)`? I tried `if type(literal_eval('1.01')) == "<type, 'float'>"`, but this did not work.

Comment: @Karnivaurus Use `isinstance(literal_eval('1.01'), int)`(replace `int` with `float` to test for real numbers).

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [`try/except` block](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-try-statement) to see if the string number can be converted into an integer:

```
def isint(x):
    try:
        int(x)
        print 'this is an int'
    except ValueError:
        print 'this is an float'
```

See a demonstration below:

```
>>> def isint(x):
...     try:
...         int(x)
...         print 'this is an int'
...     except ValueError:
...         print 'this is an float'
...
>>> isint('123')
this is an int
>>> isint('123.0')
this is an float
>>>
```

If you want to protect against the user entering a non-numerical string, you can add one more level of error handling:

```
def isint(x):
    try:
        int(x)
        print 'this is an int'
    except ValueError:
        try:
            float(x)
            print 'this is an float'
        except ValueError:
            print 'this is not a number'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> def isint(x):
    return '.' not in x

>>> isint("3.14")
False
>>> isint("3")
True
```

Comment: @MartinKonecny ahh good call, need some more robust handling of bad cases

Answer (score 0):

I think the most easy variant is using eval:

```
eval("1.7") => 1.7 => type=float
eval("1") => 1 => type=int
eval("143274892053294870824") => 143274892053294870824 => type=long
isint = lambda x: isinstance(eval(x), int)
```

Dont pass untrusted code to this function ;)